# Число и количество

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Понимаю, что слова "число" и "количество" являются синонимами. Но все-таки есть ли различия в их употреблении?

***Число*** книг в библиотеке было небольшим.
**Количество** прочитанных за лето книг не достигало и пяти.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Число" и "количество" являются синонимами только в одном значении — численный состав кого-чего.
У слова "количество" два значения (категория, характеризующая что-то со стороны числа, величины и сама величина), у слова" число" много значений. Когда возникает двойственность в понимании слова "число", нарушается сочетаемость, его стараются заменить словом "количество".

*Число (количество) книг в библиотеке было небольшим* — возможны оба варианта.

*Количество прочитанных за лето книг не достигало и пяти.*
Попробуем заменить: *число прочитанных за лето книг не достигало и пяти.*
Численность может расти, а число нет, сочетаемость слова "число" ограничена, хотя в этом значении (численный состав) возможна.
В бытовом разговоре возможно сказать и "число книг растёт и достигает какой-то величины". В книжной речи желательно такого не допускать, хотя сейчас это тоже сплошь и рядом.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!
Я не лингвист, но на мой взгляд, есть еще такой момент:
"число" = "количество" для исчисляемых, дискретных предметов (число книг, число посетителей).
Для недискретных, непрерывных сущностей такое равенство, разумеется, не работает: количество воды в стакане, количество информации (хотя строго говоря она - информация - и квантуется, но на разговорном уровне мы это не принимаем во внимание, считая её непрерывной), "выплеснуть на кого-то огромное количество эмоций".

Answer (score 0):

... без "широкого" взгляда скажу: люди, человеки - для них только "число": нельзя сказать: "большое количество людей" - это отвратительно (хотя легко принимается большинством без всяких замечаний); для (обычных, не сказочных, то есть, не говорящих человеческим языком) животных, птиц и насекомых - только "количество": "увеличилось количество собак и кошек, слонов, львов, а также мошек...", как и для неодушевленных предметов: "количество камней и деревьев", "... и потекли русла по их количеству"